# Error handling under Mongoose save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to `send` a message to the browser when there is an error saving a `document` to my `MongoDB database`. I'm using `Mongoose` as a wrapper to it.

This is my signup.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var models = mongoose.models;

exports.user = function(req, res){
    var u = new models.Users(req.body);

    u.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(400, 'Bad Request');
        }

        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

If an `err` has been detected, it displays the `err` message to the log, but won't `send` `Bad Request` to the browser.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add an `else` before `res.redirect('/');` . Its probably sending a 400 and then redirecting to /

Comment: Wow, how could I be so clumsy. Thank you dude!

Comment: better to add `return` after `res.send(400, 'Bad Request');` inside the `if` statement. If the function is the one you posted.

Answer (score 4):

**Using Promises are better and It Fix my issue for me**

I had a similar issue and fix it by using the Promise returned by the u.save() in your example.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var models = mongoose.models;

exports.user = function (req, res) {
var u = new models.Users(req.body);

u.save()
    .then((user) => {
        // If everything goes as planed
        //use the retured user document for something
         res.redirect("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //When there are errors We handle them here
        console.log(err);
        res.send(400, "Bad Request");

    });
```

};

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could `return res.redirect('/');` so code execution would stop.